# How to combine two character type variables

Tags: c, string, variables, io, character

Consider that iam creating two variables

```
              char a1,b1,c1; /*consider that im assigning*/

              a1='a',b1='b';

              /* now i want to combine a1 and b1  and assign to c1 
               i.e c1='ab' pls suggest me the code to do that. 
              Dont suggest any complex code im a begineer.
```

Comment: It cannot be archived since `c1` can save only one char (byte).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do with a regular `char` variable. To do what you want you should use an array of `char`:

```
char a1, b1, c1[2];

a1 = 'a';
b1 = 'b';

c1[0] = a1;
c1[1] = b1;
```

Comment: your way is right for assign values is char array using position.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store two characters in a `char variable`(it has only 1 byte) .

Use a char array and use `sprintf` or `snprintf` -

```
char c1[3];
sprintf(c1,"%c%c",a,b);   // or snprintf(c1,sizeof c1,"%c%c",a,b);
```